# What is f# `const` keyword

Tags: f#

What is the `const` keyword in f#. It highlights in visual studio and the error message also calls it a *keyword* as shown below:

[image]

However I could not find it in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233249.aspx or the official language spec http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf

**Question**: any docs on this reserved keyword?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's right there in the bottom of the first link you pasted:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233249.aspx

> The following tokens are reserved as keywords for future expansion of the F# language:
>
> **const**

Comment: Facepalm :) Thanks 

Answer (score 2):

```
[<Literal>]
let something = 2
```

Values that are intended to be constants can be marked with the Literal attribute. This attribute has the effect of causing a value to be compiled as a constant.
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/literals

Answer (score 0):

It's documented now https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/20089/files

Type Providers allow the use of `const` as a keyword to specify a constant literal as a type parameter argument.